# The action of GestureRecognizer does not fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I add the gesture to view as following steps:

```
@interface iCarousel () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>  
{ 
     UIPanGestureRecognizer * mPanGesture;  
     UITapGestureRecognizer * mTapGesture; 
}
@end  
@implementation iCarousel
- (void)setUp  
{
    _contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];  

    _contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;  

    /  
    mPanGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(iCarouselDidPan:)];  
    mPanGesture.delegate = self;  
    [_contentView addGestureRecognizer:mPanGesture];  

    /  
    mTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(iCarouselDidTap:)];  
    mTapGesture.delegate = self;  
    [_contentView addGestureRecognizer:mTapGesture];  

    /  
    self.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction;  
    self.isAccessibilityElement = YES;  

    [self addSubview:_contentView];  
} 
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder  
{  
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))  
    {  
        [self setUp];  
    }  
    return self;  
}  

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame  
{  
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))  
    {  
        [self setUp];  
    }  
    return self;  
}  

...  


- (void)iCarouselDidTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture  
{  
     ...  
}  


- (void)iCarouselDidPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture  
{  
     ...  
}  

...  

@end
```

Now, the method in this class

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
```

return me YES

**But, the actions iCarouselDidPan: and iCarouselDidTap: do not fire.**

The information is printed in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` method.

```
(lldb) po _contentView.gestureRecognizers 
<__NSArrayI 0x1572bec0>(  
<UIPanGestureRecognizer: 0x16dea750; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x16dea640>; target= <(action=iCarouselDidPan:, target=<iCarousel 0x16dea1b0>)>>,
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x16e8f310; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x16dea640>; target= <(action=iCarouselDidTap:, target=<iCarousel 0x16dea1b0>)>> 
)  
(lldb) po gesture 
<UIPanGestureRecognizer: 0x16dea750; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x16dea640>; target= <(action=iCarouselDidPan:, target=<iCarousel 0x16dea1b0>)>>
```

**It's only happened on devices <4s 9.3.x , 5 10.3.1> at current moment.**

Comment: What is base class of iCarousel?

Comment: @interface iCarousel : UIView

Comment: @Archer add number of tap in tap gesture

Comment: @Himanshu, I am sorry, maybe I don't understand your mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implement the following methods of protocol `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` inside your `iCarousel`:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
       shouldReceivePress:(UIPress *)press {

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I had implement the following methods of protocol `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in `iCarousel.m`

`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch`
and
`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture`

Comment: @Archer And the problem still persist?

Comment: No, I am trying your method.
But I don't know why need to add the other delegate methods.

Comment: You have 2 recognisers added to the same view. Your need to check each time if they don't make conflicts in gesture. Or just try to add 1 recogniser and check if at least 1 recogniser works for you.

Comment: I mean that the `gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer:` and `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` had implemented before.

Comment: You need to add methods that I wrote, your methods are not enough to solve the problem.

Comment: in method 'gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer:' and `gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer:`, I distinguish and deal with different gestures. **And the problem is only happened on devices <4s 9.3.x , 5 10.3.1>**

Comment: Ok, it works well now, Can you tell why need add the other delegate method?

Comment: I told you before that you have conflicting recognisers. For example, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer calling when you need to choose, if you need to handle the sound recogniser when you already handle the first. The same methods are shouldReceiveTouch and shouldReceivePress. You can add breakpoints inside these 3 methods to check when they are calling and add your custom handler.

Comment: Although I have read the official notes on this method `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`, I did not fully understand it clearly. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in .h file

**Gesture definition**

```
-(UITapGestureRecognizer*)setTapGesture{

    UITapGestureRecognizer *Tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapWithGestureRecognizer:)];
    Tap.delegate = self;
    return Tap;

}
-(void)handleTapWithGestureRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)TapGestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"tap Gesture");
}

-(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)setpanGesture{

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    return panRecognizer;

}
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:recognizer.view];
     CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
     self.YOURVIEW.center = touchLocation;
}
```

**Call Gesture or add gesture to your view**

```
[self.YOURVIEW addGestureRecognizer:[self setTapGesture]];
[self.YOURVIEW addGestureRecognizer:[self setpanGesture]];

self.YOURVIEW.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```

**Good Luck
Happy Coding.**

Comment: I will research your answer, thank you for you answer very much. The thought in your answer is really good.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cases for not working gestures .

1 - You need to enable interaction of view.

```
 [_contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

2 - Add this delegate in your class.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it maybe help others. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now, it works now, but I use the method of Roman above. I'll split up my code and use your mind